# response entities not present in quarkus eks pod

Tags: java, quarkus, amazon-eks

i have a microservice created using quarkus and deployed in an eks

I developed a Post handler that returns a response like this

```
return Response.status(code).entity(new RespuestaDTO(mensaje)).build();
```

where RespuestaDTO is a POJO that implements Serializable, nothing fancy. If i run the project in my local environment i get the right response like

```
{
  "mensajes": [
     {
       "mensaje":"some message"
     }
  ]
}
```

but when in run the project in the eks the response i get is like this

```
{}
```

any ideas ?

Comment: do you run native binary on EKS ? in your local do you run jar ? can you share your pom xml or build gradle ?

Comment: In case you run natively: try adding `@RegisterForReflection` to class `RespuestaDTO`. For more information, see [the relevant `quarkus.io` docs](https://quarkus.io/guides/writing-native-applications-tips#registering-for-reflection).